# Creating 2d string indexed tables in Lua

Tags: lua, hashtable, lua-table

I need to create a table like:

```
M = {"A"={"a1"=0, "a2"= 1}, "B"={"b1"=2,"b2"=3}}
```

but this is what I got: " '}' expected near '=' "

Is there anyway to do/simulate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo.bar` is the syntactic sugar of `foo["bar"]`, there are no double quotes in the the former syntax:

```
M = {A = {a1 = 0, a2 = 1}, B = {b1 = 2, b2 =3 }}
```

Comment: In cases where the string index is not a valid Lua identifier, you can use the general syntax of `M = { ["A"] = `....